# Enterprise Network Equipment vulnerable to heartbleed

Tags: security

On 09/04/2014 the [The Heartbleed vulerability](http://heartbleed.com/) was [disclosed by the OpenSSL team](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt).

> The Heartbleed Bug is a serious vulnerability in the popular OpenSSL cryptographic software library. This weakness allows stealing the information protected, under normal conditions, by the SSL/TLS encryption used to secure the Internet.

Can we build a list of enterprise networking devices that are vulnerable to [heartbleed](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0160)?

Comment: Naturally something in the vast ocean of network embedded systems was using vulnerable openssl libraries; however, what is the goal of your question?  Do you want to build a list of vulnerable devices?  If so, please make this a community wiki... under most circumstances I'd consider this a poll; however, a mod on another site gave me the community wiki idea for these kind of unbounded, but objectively verifiable lists... this question seems to fit.  We can add *one* answer to list all devices.  If your goal isn't to list all vulnerable devices, please clarify your intent

Comment: We also started an alternative list here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SRwLwIN38qXCuLla9eCtQjKnYsbrdlSHHbyyGCMIWTA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with any new vulnerability, it's impacts are far-reaching.  Infrastructure devices are no different.  Most of them do incorporate vulnerable OpenSSL packages.

It's nearly impossible to compile a listing of every vulnerable product<sup>**1**</sup>, since it affects anything that included OpenSSL libraries built with the original [OpenSSL TLS heartbeat implementation](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/4817504d069b4c5082161b02a22116ad75f822b1) until the heartbleed patch [was committed to OpenSSL stable branch](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/731f431497f463f3a2a97236fe0187b11c44aead); however, we can list the major vendors' products here.

## This is a community wiki, feel free to contribute.

### Aruba

> - ArubaOS 6.3.x, 6.4.x
> - ClearPass 6.1.x, 6.2.x, 6.3.x
> - **Previous versions** of these products used an earlier version of OpenSSL 
>     that is **not vulnerable**.

<sup>[OpenSSL 1.0.1 library (Heartbleed) vulnerability.](http://www.arubanetworks.com/support/alerts/aid-040814.asc)</sup>

### Checkpoint Networks

[SK 100173](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk100173&js_peid=P-114a7bc3b09-10006&partition=General&product=Security) asserts that Checkpoint products are not vulnerable.

### Cisco

The following Cisco products are affected by this vulnerability:

> - Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for iOS [CSCuo17488]
> - Cisco Desktop Collaboration Experience DX650
> - Cisco Unified 7800 series IP Phones
> - Cisco Unified 8961 IP Phone
> - Cisco Unified 9951 IP Phone
> - Cisco Unified 9971 IP Phone
> - Cisco IOS XE [CSCuo19730]
> - Cisco Unified Communications Manager (UCM) 10.0
> - Cisco Universal Small Cell 5000 Series running V3.4.2.x software
> - Cisco Universal Small Cell 7000 Series running V3.4.2.x software
> - Small Cell factory recovery root filesystem V2.99.4 or later
> - Cisco MS200X Ethernet Access Switch
> - Cisco Mobility Service Engine (MSE)
> - Cisco TelePresence Video Communication Server (VCS) [CSCuo16472]
> - Cisco TelePresence Conductor
> - Cisco TelePresence Supervisor MSE 8050
> - Cisco TelePresence Server 8710, 7010
> - Cisco TelePresence Server on Multiparty Media 310, 320
> - Cisco TelePresence Server on Virtual Machine
> - Cisco TelePresence ISDN Gateway 8321 and 3201 Series
> - Cisco TelePresence Serial Gateway Series
> - Cisco TelePresence IP Gateway Series
> - Cisco WebEx Meetings Server versions 2.x [CSCuo17528]
> - Cisco Security Manager [CSCuo19265]

<sup>[Cisco Security Advisory - OpenSSL Heartbeat Extension Vulnerability in Multiple Cisco Products](http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20140409-heartbleed)</sup>

### D-Link

> As of April 15, 2014 D-Link has no vulnerable products.

<sup>[Security Incident Response for D-Link Devices and Services](http://securityadvisories.dlink.com/security/publication.aspx?name=SAP10022)</sup>

### Fortigate

> - FortiGate (FortiOS) 5.x
> - FortiAuthenticator 3.x
> - FortiMail 5.x
> - FortiVoice
> - FortiRecorder
> - FortiADC D-Series models 1500D, 2000D and 4000D
> - FortiADC E-Series 3.x
> - Coyote Point Equalizer GX / LX 10.x

<sup>[Information Disclosure Vulnerability in OpenSSL](http://www.fortiguard.com/advisory/FG-IR-14-011/)</sup>

### F5

As of April 10, 2014 the following F5 Products / Releases are known to be vulnerable

> - BigIP LTM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP AAM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP AFM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP Analytics Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP APM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP ASM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP GTM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP Link Controller Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP PEM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BigIP PSM Versions 11.5.0 - 11.5.1 (Mgmt Interface, compat SSL ciphers)
> - BIG-IP Edge Clients for Apple iOS Versions 1.0.5, 2.0.0 - 2.0.1 (VPN)
> - BIG-IP Edge Clients for Linux Versions 6035 - 7101 (VPN)
> - BIG-IP Edge Clients for Mac OSX Versions 6035 - 7101 (VPN)
> - BIG-IP Edge Clients for Windows Versions 6035 - 7101 (VPN)

<sup>[F5 Networks SOL 15159 OpenSSL Vulnerability CVE-2014-0160](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/15000/100/sol15159.html)</sup>

### HP

As of April 10

> "We have determined the products we have investigated are not vulnerable due to either using a version of OpenSSL that is not vulnerable or are not using OpenSSL."

<sup>[HP Networking Communication: OpenSSL HeartBleed Vulnerability](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/docs/advisories/HPNetworkingSecurityAdvisory-OpenSSL-HeartbleedVulnerability.pdf)</sup>

### Huawei

As of April 14

> The investigation has been completed and it is confirmed that some Huawei products are affected. Huawei has prepared a fixing plan and started the development and test of fixed versions. Huawei will release an SA as soon as possible. Please stay tuned.

<sup>[Security Notice-Statement on OpenSSL Heartbeat Extension Vulnerability](http://www.huawei.com/en/security/psirt/security-bulletins/security-notices/hw-331856.htm)</sup>

### Juniper

Vulnerable Products

> - Junos OS 13.3R1
> - Odyssey client 5.6r5 and later
> - SSL VPN (IVEOS) 7.4r1 and later, and SSL VPN (IVEOS) 8.0r1 and later (Fixed code is listed in the "Solution" section)
> - UAC 4.4r1 and later, and UAC 5.0r1 and later (Fixed code is listed in the "Solution" section)
> - Junos Pulse (Desktop) 5.0r1 and later, and Junos Pulse (Desktop) 4.0r5 and later
> - Network Connect (windows only) version 7.4R5 to 7.4R9.1 & 8.0R1 to 8.0R3.1. (This client is only impacted when used in FIPS mode.)
> - Junos Pulse (Mobile) on Android version 4.2R1 and higher.
> - Junos Pulse (Mobile) on iOS version 4.2R1 and higher. (This client is only impacted when used in FIPS mode.)

<sup>[Juniper Knowledge Center - 2014-04 Out of Cycle Security Bulletin: Multiple products affected by OpenSSL "Heartbleed" issue (CVE-2014-0160)](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=JSA10623)</sup>

### Palo Alto Networks

[PAN-OS was not affected by heartbleed](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2014/04/palo-alto-networks-addresses-heartbleed-vulnerability-cve-2014-0160/)

---

## Workarounds

Disable resources that utilize SSL, if you can, and rely on SSH which, as [Mike Pennington commented](https://superuser.com/a/739350/77053) is not vulnerable.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This listing was taken on 10 April 2014, vendors may still have their products under investigation. This listing is **not** a vulnerability guideline, and only serves to give the original poster an understanding of the scope of impact on networking equipment.</sub>

Comment: FYI, [OpenSSH is not vulnerable to heartbleed](http://superuser.com/a/739350/77053).  Also the scare numbers about heartbleed affecting 60% of the internet are bogus.  Only OpenSSL libraries built within the last two years are vulnerable (specifically, those with [this TLS heartbeat commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/4817504d069b4c5082161b02a22116ad75f822b1)).  That number is *way* lower than 60% of the internet.

Comment: Edited to reflect that information.  Thanks for the heads up.  I assumed that information was just click-bait, I'll remove that as well.

Comment: Do you happen to know what version of cisco IOS XE is affected?

Comment: @Phil if you follow the link to the Cisco's page there will be a reference to the bug with detailed information.